# For $N, M \unlhd G$ relation between $MN/(M\cap N)$ and $N/(M\cap N)\times M/(M\cap N)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $N, M \unlhd G$. Is $MN/(N\cap M)$ isomorphic to some subgroup of 
$$
 N/(N\cap M) \times M/(N\cap M)
$$
and how to prove this?

Comment: Duplicated topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this:
(**resource:** The Theory of Finite Groups: An Introduction. Hans Kurzweil Bernd Stellmacher pp31)
[image]